# How to get Data To Wordpress TinyMCE Listbox from Database

Tags: php, wordpress, listbox, tinymce

I am developing a WordPress shot-code plugin.

i have added a listbox in TinyMCE and i need to load data to TinyMCE from wordpress database. i can not hard code the listbox values since all my shortcodes values are saved in wordpress database.

is there any possible way to do this ?

```
(function() {
    tinymce.PluginManager.add('AP_tc_button', function( editor, url ) {
        editor.addButton( 'AP_tc_button', {
            text: 'My test button',
            icon: 'wp_code',
            onclick: function() {
    editor.windowManager.open( {
        title: 'Select Your AD',
        body: [
        {
            type: 'listbox', 
            name: 'level', 
            label: 'Header level', 
           values: getValues()
        }],
        onsubmit: function( e ) {
            editor.insertContent('dd');
        }
    });
}
        });
    });


})();


function getValues() {
     //Set new values to myKeyValueList (i need this values get from the db)
tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList = [{text: 'newtext', value: 'newvalue'}];
      return tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.myKeyValueList;
   }
```

Comment: Can You Put Sample Code that you developed ?

Answer (score 0):

if it helps someone who visit this post.

My solution was retrieving the data through a ajax request. The trick is doing a synchronous request (async: false).

```
function getValues() {

    var data = {'action': 'getValuesAjax'};

    var q = jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: data,
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json'
    });      

    var values = q.responseJSON;
    return values;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore...I am not sure whether this is due to WordPress updates or the deprecation of async false